# import java ImportError: No module named java

Tags: java, python, unix, jython

I seemed to have hit a roadblock and can't figure this out at all, can anyone help me figure out why I am unable to import the java module?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./datasource_config.py", line 3, in ?
    import java
ImportError: No module named java
```

java:

```
13:30:05 # which java
/usr/bin/java
```

beginning of script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import java
from java.util import Properties
from java.io import FileInputStream
from org.python.modules import time
lineSep = java.lang.System.getProperty('line.separator')

def datasource(cluster,user,password,url,env,jdbc_driver,timeOut,maxConn,minConn,reapTime,unusdTimeout,agedTimeout):

    #Declare global variables 
    global    AdminConfig 
    global    AdminControl
```

Can someone help me determine what this means?

```
13:45:07 # ./jython -v /opt/websphere/datasource_config.py
*sys-package-mgr*: can't create package cache dir, '/usr/lib/jython-25/cachedir/packages'
import: 'exceptions' as org.python.core.exceptions in builtin modules
import: 'site' as /usr/lib/jython-25/Lib/site.py
import: 'sys' as sys in builtin modules
import: 'os' as /usr/lib/jython-25/Lib/os.py
import: 'errno' as org.python.modules.errno in builtin modules
import: 'posix' as org.python.modules.posix.PosixModule in builtin modules
import: 'posixpath' as /usr/lib/jython-25/Lib/posixpath.py
import: 'stat' as /usr/lib/jython-25/Lib/stat.py
import: 'Properties' as java class
import: 'FileInputStream' as java class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/websphere/datasource_config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from org.python.modules import time
ImportError: cannot import name time
```

Comment: You may have `java` installed but that's not the same as a python module called `java` that you can import in python. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You're attempting to call java from within a python script. So this question doesn't really make sense

Comment: Import the python module called java

Comment: Did you install a Python module called java?

Comment: You've changed the question now. Does `org.python.modules ` exist? Is it on your python path?

Comment: @doctorlove I'm not sure how to check that, how can i do that? The original problem was solved by running this as jython rather than python.

Comment: turns out i just needed to do import time rather than #from org.python.modules import time

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading here. The problem is likely to be that you dont have permissions in directory /usr/lib/jython-25/cachedir/packages and possibly the parent directory cachedir too. If you look at the first line of the output when wsadmin.sh starts, it actually implies this.