# python script- how to import System

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to get the following to work in a python script and have referred to this [import java ImportError: No module named java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612235/import-java-importerror-no-module-named-java), but it did not solve my issue.

I am trying the following in a python script (version 2.6.6) :

```
from java.lang import System
```

and the get following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./myscript.py", line 3, in <module>
  from java.lang import System
```

Is the above possible in a python script?

Please note following commands work fine

- `java -version` and `javac -version` (**JAVA_HOME/PATH** have been set ok)
- `python` (invokes the python shell ok)

Comment: It sounds like youre tryin to import a java module into python. You cant do this. they are different languages. You could possibly use jython but I havent used it myself so I dont know much about it.

Comment: similar example -  from java.io import Date.                                           There is a way to make this work in a python script. That's what I am looking for here.

Comment: There is a way to make java modules run in python? Do you have a reference for this? Why are you using python if you need java modules, why not just use java? or why not just use the equivalent python modules?

Comment: "*Is the above possible in a Python script?*" That depends on what you mean by "Python". `from java.lang import System` will work in a **Jython** script. It will not work in a **CPython** script. These are different implementations of the same language.

Comment: sure I want to know how this import System works in jython. Thx mzjn.

Answer (score 1):

python has a sys library but it is significantly different than System in java's standard library.

```
import sys
```